# Trouble with method taking the correct type

Tags: java, methods, input, types

So, I'm very new to Java (just started class last week), and I'm trying to write a class to manipulate prime numbers. I'm pretty good with python, but have no idea what I'm doing here apparently. When I try to use the `isPrime` method I get the error:

"cannot invoke isPrime() on the primitive type int."

Any help? As near as I can tell, the method should take an `int` and assign it to the method variable `p`. Do I have something backwards? Thanks for your help!

```
public class Prime {

    private int prime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int seventeen = 17;
        int five = 5;
        int twentyFour = 24;
        System.out.println(twentyFour.isPrime());
        System.out.println(seventeen.isPrime());
        System.out.println(five.isPrime());
    }

    public Prime(int p) {
        prime = p;
    }

    public boolean isPrime(int p){
        int i=0;
        if(p==1 || p==0)
            return false;
        for(i=2; i<=p; i++) {
            if(p%i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getPrime(){
        prime++;
        while(!prime.isPrime()){
            prime++;
        }
        return prime;       
    }

    public void reset(){
        prime = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The key here is that the method *takes* an `int`. You don't invoke `isPrime` *on* an `int`. That means you pass an `int` as the *argument*. You can only invoke methods on an object.

Comment: Also, you have to make `isPrime` method static like `public void static isPrime(int p)` to invoke it inside main method.

Comment: Incidently, while you're here; multiline braceless ifs are generally considered bad practice in java; because (unlike in Python) tabs are just for human viewers, they are ignored by the compiler. So if you leave out braces bugs can very easily arise (e.g. if you try to add a new statement within an if statement without adding the braces)

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

The `isPrime` method accepts an argument of type `int` which is not provided when its invoked.

```
   //Method requires an argument of type int to be provided.
   public boolean isPrime(int p){
       //Method body omitted
   }

   public int getPrime(){
        prime++;

        //this method attempts to invoke isPrime without supplying an int argument
        while(!prime.isPrime()){
            prime++;
        }
        return prime;       
    }
```

This could be corrected by supplying the argument when invoking the method.  I would also suggest making the method static since it does not rely upon any internal fields within `Prime`

### Resolution

```
public static boolean isPrime(int p){
    int i=0;
    if(p==1 || p==0)
        return false;
    for(i=2; i<=p; i++) {
        if(p%i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Usage
Prime.isPrice(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call it something like this:

```
new Prime().isPrime(26);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `if(!prime.isPrime())`, try `!isPrime(prime)` and call it from `main method` by

```
Prime p = new Prime()
p.isPrime(prime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `isPrime()` belongs to the class `Prime` not `int` (`int` can't have any methods anyway as it is a primative, not an object).

So the following is a valid piece of code using this method

```
Prime primeChecker=new Prime();
boolean isPrime=primeChecker.isPrime(17);
```

Its worth noting that the method `isPrime()` doesn't actually use any state of the class `Prime` so it could be declared static. In which case it could be used without creating a `Prime` object

```
 boolean isPrime=isPrime(17);
```

if `isPrime` declared as:

```
public static int getPrime(){
    ......      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instanciate the class and call isprime wih the int value as Parameter.

```
Prime prime = new Prime();
System.out.println(prime.isPrime(twentyFour));
System.out.println(prime.isPrime(seventeen));
System.out.println(prime.isPrime(five));
```

And Change:

```
while(!prime.isPrime()){
```

To

```
while(!isPrime(prime)){
```

Comment: This is not enough, `getPrime()` will give error now